# Problema de alcance em C++

Tags: c++, vector, scope

Sou iniciante na programação em C++ e me deparei com um problema quando tentava executar meu código no **atom**, usando o pacote gpp-compiler e o MinGW: 'function' was not declared in this scope (l.8). Não entendi o motivo do erro, alguém pode me ajudar?

Aqui está a função main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int* a;
    a = function(50);
    for(int d = 0; d < a.length; d++){
       .
       .
       .
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

e o arquivo header:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#include <vector>

int* function(int num){
    std::vector<int> c;
       .
       .
       .     
    int z[(int)c.size()];
    for(int b = 0; b < (int)c.size(); b++){
        z[b] = c.at(b);
    }
    return z;
}

#endif
```

Pra ser mais específico, a mensagem de erro foi assim:

> ...\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>
> ...\main.cpp:9:18: error: 'function' was not declared in this scope
>   a = function(50);
>
> ...\main.cpp:10:23: error: request for member 'length' in 'a', which
>   is of non-class type 'int*'   for(int d = 0; d < a.length; d++){

Comment: Se eu não deixei escapar nada olhando por cima, provavelmente tem outro erro que está provocando este.

Comment: Retornar um *array* local criado na função só por si já está errado,e sobre um `int*` não pode fazer `.length`. Apesar desses dois erros experimentei compilar o seu código e não obtive o erro que indica. Como está a fazer a compilação ? a mão (se sim como?) ou num IDE ? (se sim qual ?)

Comment: Você está usando o Visual Studio? o #include "stdafx.h" está como o primeiro include (ou antes do seu header)?

Comment: A pergunta foi atualizada.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder retornar z, sendo um ponteiro têm alocar memorica primeiro

```
int * z = new int[(int)c.size()];
```

depois ter o cuidado de fazer delete quando o array não for mais preciso nesse caso na função main.

```
delete a;
```

Os arrays em C++ são como em C, não tem o atributo "length" ao contrario do java, para saber o tamanho do array é necessário outra forma de guardar o tamanho, para evitar esses problemas aconselho a usar o vector.